# Catch two different click event inside a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an image and a check box placed inside a div.
There are two different events of click in it. One is :

1. **When I click the check-box the check-box should be selected(checked)** and the other is
2. **When I click the image a light-box should appear.**

What happening is; when I click the image, the light-box appear but when I click the check-box, again the light-box is appearing.

```
<div class="divWrap">
    <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="abc.jpg">
        <div id="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="checkbox1" name="check1" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to code it properly in jQuery.
Can anyone help?

Comment: please read "how to use" section in http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".imageWrap img").click(function() {
    alert("image clicked");
});

$(".imageWrap checkbox").click(function() {
    alert("checkbox clicked");
});
```

---

```
$(".imageWrap").click(function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if ( $target.is("img") ) {
        alert("image clicked");
    }
    else if ( $target.is("checkbox") ) {
        alert("checkbox clicked");
    }
});
```